# Implementing two functions in Mips assembly that finds the length of a word

Tags: mips

I need help creating two functions. The first function needs to find the length of a word. For input the function takes the address of the first character of the word and return the length of the word (the words are in an array).

The second  function needs to delete the words in the array that had more characters than the average (counting from all the characters in the array) so lets say the average is 4 characters in a word, all words that have more than 4 characters need to be deleted.

UPDATE: prntscr.com/ezjylq

Comment: how long how you tried by your self can you please add some code

Comment: i dont have idea how to make the entrance of the function (every 1st character of each word)

Answer (score 0):

I give you two example code I hope this help.

This code finding the length of arbitrary ASCII string

**Given string:**

```
"Hello\n"
```

**Output:**

```
6
```

Code:

```
.data
    message: .asciiz "Hello\n"
.text

main:
    li $t1,0
    la $t0,message         #load message to t0

loop:
    lb   $a0,0($t0)        #load one byte of t0 to a0
    beqz $a0,done          #branch if a0 = 0
    addi $t0,$t0,1         #increment t0
    addi $t1,$t1,1         #increment the counter t1
    j     loop
done:

    li   $v0,1            #print an integer
    add  $a0, $0,$t1      #add the counter to a0
    syscall

    li   $v0,10           #exit program
    syscall
```

This is a function printing "Hello World".

```
.data
message: .asciiz "Hello World.\n"

.text
main:

jal displayMessage

li $v0,10       #exit function
syscall


displayMessage:
li $v0,4        #printing string 
la $a0,message  #save the message to argument $a0
syscall

jr $ra
```

Comment: it does help a bit, but  here is the idea i have tell me if its right or wrong or i need to change smth: Create a while loop that will go through the whole array until it reaches '0' (or null) the end of the array. Now inside the loop i need to call the function for counting words and also characters and then return the average character number, then i need new while loop that will go again through the whole array to delete the words that have more than the average characcter number..

Comment: The first one also loop through array until it reach '0' or null is possible and easy, If you look closer to my first example code, it actually do exactly this what you want. The other part of your description you should try i think it's also possible to implement that too.

Comment: yeah its easier to read, now can i add function inside(below) beqz for the word/character counter?

Comment: You may try it.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/161498/a-clock-program-in-mips-assembly-that-start-ticking-from-5958. this maybe helps